# django 2 path() слэш в переменной

Tags: django, path

вот пример: "/category/falke-premium/p-woman/"

уровней может быть сколько угодно - как мне задать правильно в path()

"/category/level0/level1/level2/level3/"

```
, path('category/<str:cat_uri>/', filter_view.as_view(), {'app': 'wares', 'mnu_code': 'categorys', }, name='category')
```

так не работает - без слеша тоже не работает

не могу понять как сделать

Comment: Написать `slug` вместо `str`.

Comment: **path('product/<slug:wre_uri>', detail_view.as_view(), {'app' : 'wares', 'mnu_code' : 'wares','breadcrumbs' : True}, name='detail')**

`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('falke-woman/kolgotki-falke/kolgotki-40803-trimming-ti-winter-1617-26',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product\\/(?P<wre_uri>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']`